# Can't select the quota edit option for a resource even with owner role GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was using the free tier account and I got the error after which I upgraded. I got a confirmation email that my account is upgraded. But I still face the same trouble.
For reference I am trying to modify the BigQuery Reservation API quota. And the alert message reads:

```
Edit is not allowed for this quota.
```

Comment: Please update your question with more details - include screenshots or commands you're using to create a reservation.

Comment: Also, wait a few hours after upgrading. If you continue to have problems, open a support ticket with Google Cloud Billing.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to confirm the status of your account; you can do it via Cloud Console:

> 1. Sign in to the Manage [billing accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) in the Google Cloud
>    Console.
> 2. If you have more than one Cloud Billing account, select the name of
>    the Cloud Billing account you want to view.
> 3. On the Billing Account Overview page, look for the Credit info card.
>
> - If the Cloud Billing account is still limited to a Free Trial Cloud
>   Billing account, you will see a Free trial credit info card.
>   This card displays the status of any remaining free trial credits, and
>   provides an Upgrade button.
> - If the Cloud Billing account is upgraded to a paid account, you will
>   see a Promotional credits info card.
>   This card displays the status of any remaining free trial credits. To
>   view the details of the free trial, click Credit details.

If your account is upgraded to a paid version and you still can't change the quotas wait 24 hours just as [John Hanley suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300845/cant-select-the-quota-edit-option-for-a-resource-even-with-owner-role-gcp#comment124285852_70300845).

If you still cannot make the changes contact [billing support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) (which is always free) to get immediate help.

If for some reason they are unable to help you then please report this to Google's IssueTracker and provide as much details as possible which may help to resolve your issue and help others in the future if this turns out to be a bug of some sort.